# JAVAFX -- Is there something at this X/Y position?

Tags: java, javafx

I was wondering if there is some functionality in JavaFX which allows you to detect whether there is some object (or something) at a certain getLayoutX/Y() position? And then return it to you.

So for example, I have a Node positioned at X0 and Y1; if I inputted X0 and Y1, it would return that object, but if I did X1, Y1, then it would return null.

Anything of the sort in JavaFX?

Comment: There is nothing like that in the API, to my knowledge. Why do you need this? Perhaps there is another way to do whatever it is you're trying to do...

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'll try making my own scanner then.

Basically I'm working on some collision detection, and if there's an object at (playerPosX+X && playerPosY +Y) then player can't move there.

I was thinking of just making a giant grid of nodes, but it ended up being too slow (I had like 1000+ objects, and that's not meant to even be the minimum).

Comment: Is there a way to tell if a pixel at X1 Y0 is a certain colour?

Comment: I've implemented an [example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) doing collision detection that works well with 1000+ objects. This checks for collisions between all possible pairs of objects (so for 1000 objects, 500,000 collision tests per frame).

Comment: You can check colors on a pixel by pixel basis from an image (using a `PixelReader`), so in theory you could `snapshot` your node and then use a pixel reader on the resulting image. Not sure that performance would be particularly good though.

Comment: Could I take a "snapshot" of the entire scene as an image? So then I could scan that.

Comment: [Yes, certainly.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) But again, I think it would likely perform less well than just keeping track of where the nodes are in your data model and iterating through them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, there is internal API impl_pickNode(...) that you can call on a root node to obtain topmost node. However, [here](http://fxexperience.com/2016/01/node-picking-in-javafx/) is a cleaner version of it. Alternatively, if all your nodes have just one parent, then

```
root.getChildren()
    .stream()
    .filter(n -> n.getLayoutX() == X0 && n.getLayoutY() == Y0)
    .findAny();
```

which returns an `Optional` that either wraps your object at X0, Y0, or wraps null if there is no object at that position.

The solutions above are ad hoc and are fine for a tiny project. If, however, you want a better underlying design of the program (I'm assuming a game?), as James_D pointed out you will be better off by using a model, separate from view, where you keep your objects and go through their positions to see if there is an object at that position. The code might look like this:

```
public Optional<GameObject> getObjectAt(Point2D position) {
    return gameObjects.stream()
                      .filter(obj -> obj.getX() == position.getX()
                                  && obj.getY() == position.getY())
                      .findAny();
}
```

If it is possible to have more than one object at a given position, the above can then be generalized to something like this:

```
public List<GameObject> getObjects(Predicate<GameObject> predicate) {
    return gameObjects.stream()
                      .filter(predicate)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

which you can call with:

```
getObjects(obj -> obj.getX() == X0
               && obj.getY() == Y0
               && obj.getType() == Type.WALL);
```